# Which is best: RC5, RC6, CAST-128, LOKI97, or MARS?

Tags: encryption, rc6, rc5, mars

Considering speed and security, which is best:  RC5, RC6, CAST-128, LOKI97, or MARS?

What does the scoreboard look like?

(I'm asking about the abstract math concept, not related to any code implementation. However, hearing about code implementations would be interesting.)

Comment: Why these? Why not SHA2, SHA3, Blake2, and Blake3?

Comment: Well, mine is a "no profit" question. Basically im asking just to know more about these ciphers compared, im not gonna use them for anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CAST-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST-128) has 64-bit block size. Such block size is obsolete. Don't use such block size (thus don't use CAST-128), unless you must.

[LOKI97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOKI97) is broken, see Lars R. Knudsen & Vincent Rijmen's [*Weaknesses in LOKI97*](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-366.pdf). Don't use it.

[RC5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5) with it's originally suggested parameters (64-bit block size, 128-bit key, 12 rounds) is broken, see Alex Biryukov & Eyal Kushilevitz's [*Improved cryptanalysis of RC5*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0054119). Although that paper suggests parameters for the 128-bit block version, I'll pretend RC5 is obsoleted by [RC6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC6).

This leaves [MARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MARS_(cipher)) and [RC6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC6) as competitors. Neither algorithm is close to broken AFAIK. They have been discussed and compared by NIST's [*Report on the Development of the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)*](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/106/3/j63nec.pdf). RC6 is found to be faster, significantly so in hardware. RC6 is simpler in my view, but it has one drawback: it uses variable rotation, which is hard to make fast and constant-time on some low-end CPUs lacking a [barrel shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter) (including modern CPUs, e.g. some variants of ARM Cortex M0).

If I desperately needed a block cipher (ruling out a simpler stream cipher like [ChaCha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20#ChaCha_variant)) and for some reason was facing the choice in the question (thus could not use [AES/Rijndael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)), I'd probably use [MARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MARS_(cipher)), unless speed was paramount and I knew for certain no CPU lacking a barrel shifter would ever be used (in which case I'd consider [RC6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC6))

Addition: If I was stuck to a 64-bit block cipher among those of the question, I may use [CAST-128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST-128): it's unbroken AFAIK, and even endorsed by [ISO/IEC 18033-3:2010](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/fr/#iso:std:iso-iec:18033:-3:ed-2:v1:en), reviewed 2020.

Comment: Thats pretty clear, thanks! Just a little question, you wrote that both CAST128 and RC5 are obsolate, so, if you would pick one of them which one would you get? why?